# AutoMapper - subObject stay null when mapping back to DTO from ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, automapper, automapper-3

I have this map:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente, CadastroModule.Model.Cliente>().ReverseMap();
});
```

CadastroModule.Model.Cliente (MVVM MODEL):

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoCEP { get; set;}
    public string EnderecoBairro { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoLogradouro { get; set; }
    public int EnderecoNumero { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoComplemento { get; set; }
}
```

Sistema.DataEntities.Models (POCO):

```
public class Cliente : Entity
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        Endereco = new Endereco();
    }

    public int ClienteID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }//1 pra 1 (Complex type EF)
}
```

Sistema.DataEntities.Models (POCO):

```
public class Endereco : Entity
{
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

}
```

When i try this its run perfectly:

```
var t = _clienteService.ClienteService_GetAll().Project().To<Cliente>();
```

But when i need to back to poco i get trouble:

```
Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente clifinal = Mapper.Map<Cliente, Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente>(ObCliente);
```

**My result:**

[image]

Why the Endereco object is with null values?

Comment: Can you show your `Mapper.CreateMap` call for the classes in question?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see it up there, sorry

Comment: yes... thats only a prototype i only have this map. i put it all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automapper isn't built as much for "unflattening" objects. Your Model --> ViewModel mapping works by convention; the "Endereco" prefix in the destination tells AutoMapper to look in a nested object.

To get this to work the other way, you'll have to add a mapping manually from `CadastroModule.Model.Cliente` to `Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Endereco` and then use that mapping in the reverse mapping from `CadastroModule.Model.Cliente` to `Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, CadastroModule.Model.Cliente>()
    .ReverseMap()
    // Map the `Endereco` property from `Cliente`
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Endereco, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

cfg.CreateMap<CadastroModule.Model.Cliente, Endereco>();
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bairro, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoBairro))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CEP, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoCEP))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Complemento, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoComplemento))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Logradouro, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoLogradouro))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Numero, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoNumero));
```

Rather than map every property of `Endereco`, you could register `Endereco` as a source prefix instead:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, CadastroModule.Model.Cliente>()
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Endereco, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Endereco");
cfg.CreateMap<CadastroModule.Model.Cliente, Endereco>();
```

This solution presented, I think [the author's post on two way mapping](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/) is worth a read. Essentially, AutoMapper was not built to map *back onto* domain entities. Of course you can use it however you wish, but that might explain why this kind of scenario is not supported out of the box.

Comment: If its not a good thing for this scenario... you have other tool? I found something about ValueInjecter... its a good way?
Have in mind thats a propotype... the better the tool, less worry.

Comment: To "protect" your domain, you might just set properties manually. Again, you *can* use AutoMapper for this, it is just not how it was originally designed from what I understand.

Comment: What i really need is only a convention based mapper... and i think that Value Injecter http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com will be the better for me... its supports unflattening. Thanks for the help.